# Strange behaviour in make for static library

Tags: c, makefile

I'm facing a strange behaviour after upgrading `make` from 3.81 to 4.3.
This makefile describes the build of a static library in older GNU syntax:

```
LIBNAME = testlib.a

OBJ_FILES = \
            $(LIBNAME)(test1.o) \
            $(LIBNAME)(test2.o)
            
all: $(LIBNAME)
            
$(LIBNAME): $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(RANLIB) $@
```

The behaviour with `make` **4.3** is that the lib is always generated, no matter whether the source files have been changed or not.
In the output of `make -p`, it seems that `make` is executing implicit rules and searches for `test1.o` and `test2.o` in the directory but since they weren't there, it generates them new from source, adding them with `ar` command and later removing them from directory.

In version **3.81**, it checked directly in `testlib.a` for `test1.o` and no other rules were executed if it was found.

So must this makefile be rewritten, or is there another possibility to get the old behaviour?

Edit:

Now tested on another Linux Mint system, with GNU `make` 4.3, same behaviour.

As MadScientist mentioned, output of `make --trace`:

```
<builtin>: update target 'test1.o' due to: test1.c
cc    -c -o test1.o test1.c
<builtin>: update target 'testlib.a(test1.o)' due to: test1.o
ar rv -U testlib.a test1.o
r - test1.o
rm test1.o
```

Comment: I do not reproduce the described misbehavior with GNU `make` 4.2.1 or 4.3.

Comment: I don't know why you're running `make -p` to debug this.  `-p` tells make to print its database, that's not very helpful.  Why not use `make --trace` or the full `make -d`?

Comment: When posting to SO it usually helps if you use the POSIX locale to get messages in English; for example: `LC_ALL=POSIX make --trace` or something like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you **sure** the only difference between the two situations is the version of `make`?  That is, are you running this on the same system with two different versions of `make`, or are you running it on two different systems with different versions of the OS and/or compiler?

I'll bet that in addition to using a different version of `make` you're also using a different version of binutils.

Someone at some point in the last 10 years or so got the amazingly bright idea (not!) that the default behavior of the `ar` program should be changed from what it has been for 50 years or so, and made "deterministic".  Now, I'm all for reproducible builds but this should be an opt-in capability, not an opt-out capability, especially since enabling "deterministic mode" in `ar` completely destroys make's ability to manage archives.

You will have to disable deterministic mode by hand if you want this to work.  Try adding:

```
ARFLAGS += -U
```

and see if it fixes things.

BTW in your makefile example above you forgot to define `RANLIB` so it won't work (that variable is not a built-in for GNU Make).

Comment: You're right, also the system has changed and with it the compiler and binutils. Yes RANLIB is defined in the original Makefile. I'll try to modify the ARFLAGS as you mentioned.

Comment: Thats the solution, adding -U to ARFLAGS. Thank you.